# How to make the Fetch API return a key and its value from a JSON file, rather than returning the entire file in console

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

I'm trying to use fetch() to parse the key:values in my JSON file in order to use those values in a carousel (I'm grabbing image paths from the JSON file.) When I set it to log in the console, instead of returning individual keys and values, it instead returns the entirety of the array.

This is my code currently. Basic fetch().

```
fetch('http:/localhost/x/y/z/propimg.json')
.then( res => res.json() )
.then( (id) => {
  console.log({id});
})
```

Is it even possible to do what I want with fetch? There's thousands of IDs in the JSON file, and there are many common IDs which are attached to individual file paths to images. For example:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "31514711",
      "image": "/localhost/x/y/z/img/31514711-0.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "31514711",
      "image": "/localhost/x/y/z/img/31514711-1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "31514711",
      "image": "/localhost/x/y/z/img/31514711-2.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "31514711",
      "image": "/localhost/x/y/z/img/31514711-3.jpg"
    }
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to parse these out in order to attach them to an image carousel that displays all images associated with the "id" in the file.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

---

Per the comments, this is an example of the console output:

```
{id: Array(1)}
    id: Array(1)
        0: Array(276512)
            [0 ... 9999] (etc.)
                [0 ... 999] (etc.)
                    0: {id: "31514711", image: "/localhost/x/y/z/img/31514711-0.jpg"}
                    1: {id: "31514711", image: "/localhost/x/y/z/img/31514711-1.jpg"}
                    2: {id: "31514711", image: "/localhost/x/y/z/img/31514711-2.jpg"}
                    3: {id: "31514711", image: "/localhost/x/y/z/img/31514711-3.jpg"}
                    4: {id: "31514711", image: "/localhost/x/y/z/img/31514711-4.jpg"}
                    5: {id: "31514711", image: "/localhost/x/y/z/img/30093175-0.jpg"}
                    6: {id: "30093175", image: "/localhost/x/y/z/img/30093175-1.jpg"}
                    7: {id: "30093175", image: "/localhost/x/y/z/img/30093175-2.jpg"}
                    8: {id: "30093175", image: "/localhost/x/y/z/img/30093175-3.jpg"}
                    (etc.)
```

---

EDIT: Updated code to show what I'm trying to do, hopefully more clearly:

```
fetch('localhost/x/y/z/propimg.json') 
 .then( (res) => res.json() ) 
 .then( (output => { 
  var img = output; 
  for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) { 
   console.log("ID:", img[i].id); 
   console.log("Image:", img[i].image); 
  } 
}))
```

In other words, I want to return each ID and its image path. What I'm trying to do is feed this into react-image-gallery and have it display only the images associated with the ID.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You can resolve the promise returned by `fetch()` with anything you want. If you showed an example of the data you'd like to return, perhaps we could help

Comment: An api request can't change what's being sent from your backend server. It's the backend's job to return what you want. If you don't have control over the response, you can parse the response yourself after you fetch it.

Comment: @rvor that's not what I was asking for at all. Your API call returns data to you. What about that data is not satisfactory to your application? What data do you want to be working with?

Comment: @rvor To echo what Phil is saying, you really need to change what's happening server-side here.  There is way too much data you're sending back from the server.  The Fetch API doesn't know or care how you interact with your server (other than it being via HTTP).  It's up to you to limit the data you return.

Comment: I want to be able to put the key:value pairs in variables, I suppose, and use the variables to get the application to display the image that's in the folder. For example, something like var ids = key("id") and var images = key("images"), then returning the values those keys are associated with. I'm using this in conjunction with react-image-gallery.

Comment: @rvor when you `console.log({id})` you are not destructuring, but putting another pair of curly braces around the id array object. Remove the outer pair of square brackets form your source JSON file and then you can `console.log(id)`.